# Why doesn't my SQL query select any row from the sqllite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys

In my database, I have two tables "classes" and "classes_sessions", I have created a foreign key linking the two tables. I am trying to retrieve data from these tables using the query below

**Code**

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +
            TABLE_CLASSES +
            " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
            " ON " +
            TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID +
            " = " + TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
            " WHERE " +
            TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID +
            " = " + String.valueOf(id);
```

in the `getAllSectionsByClassesID()` method below

```
 public ArrayList<SectionsBean> getAllSectionsByClassesID(long id){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +
            TABLE_CLASSES +
            " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
            " ON " +
            TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID +
            " = " + TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
            " WHERE " +
            TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID +
            " = " + String.valueOf(id);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ArrayList<SectionsBean> sectionsBeanList = new ArrayList<SectionsBean>();

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);


    Log.i("Query details", String.valueOf(cursor));
    Log.d("DataDetails", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


        ClassesBean classesBean = new ClassesBean();
        classesBean.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_ID)));
        classesBean.setClasses_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME)));


        SectionsBean sectionsBean = new SectionsBean();
        sectionsBean.setSectionsID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID)));
        sectionsBean.setSections_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME)));



        sectionsBean.setClassesBean(classesBean);
        sectionsBeanList.add(sectionsBean);

    }
    return sectionsBeanList;

}
```

But it does not return any thing. I am using the line to check for data returned by the cursor in the database `Log.d("DataDetails", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));` and the result is blank. There are contents in both tables as seen below

**Database contents**

Classes Table

```
-05 22:06:23.728 31258-31310/com.example.demeainc.demea D/DataC: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@88a8264
                                                                     0 {
                                                                        classes_id=1
                                                                        class_item_index=null
                                                                        classes_name=jss1
                                                                        classes_codename=null
                                                                        classes_sections_id=null
                                                                        classes_teachers=null
                                                                        classes_students=null
                                                                     }
                                                                     1 {
                                                                        classes_id=2
                                                                        class_item_index=null
                                                                        classes_name=villa
                                                                        classes_codename=null
                                                                        classes_sections_id=null
                                                                        classes_teachers=null
                                                                        classes_students=null
                                                                     }
                                                                     2 {
                                                                        classes_id=3
                                                                        class_item_index=null
                                                                        classes_name=two
                                                                        classes_codename=null
                                                                        classes_sections_id=null
                                                                        classes_teachers=null
                                                                        classes_students=null
                                                                     }
                                                                     <<<<<
```

Database contents for the sessions table

```
03-05 22:09:03.943 31258-31258/com.example.demeainc.demea D/DataS: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@eaadf23
                                                                     0 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=1
                                                                        classes_sections_name=cooolanet
                                                                        classes_sections_description=bbdbn
                                                                     }
                                                                     1 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=2
                                                                        classes_sections_name=morrals
                                                                        classes_sections_description=mills
                                                                     }
                                                                     2 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=3
                                                                        classes_sections_name=live
                                                                        classes_sections_description=bxn
                                                                     }
                                                                     3 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=4
                                                                        classes_sections_name=testing2
                                                                        classes_sections_description=coll
                                                                     }
                                                                     4 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=5
                                                                        classes_sections_name=tool
                                                                        classes_sections_description=vi
                                                                     }
                                                                     5 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=6
                                                                        classes_sections_name=colls
                                                                        classes_sections_description=
                                                                     }
                                                                     6 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=7
                                                                        classes_sections_name=more
                                                                        classes_sections_description=coll
                                                                     }
                                                                     7 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=8
                                                                        classes_sections_name=testing
                                                                        classes_sections_description=ttt
                                                                     }
                                                                     8 {
                                                                        classes_sections_ids=9
                                                                        classes_sections_name=threevill
                                                                        classes_sections_description=cool
                                                                     }
                                                                     <<<<<
```

More details on table creation.

```
// create classes_table sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASS_ITEM_INDEX + " NUMBER,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_CODENAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CLASSES_TEACHERS
        + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_STUDENTS + " VARCHAR,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS  + "(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " + ");";

//create sections sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR" + ")";
```

What could be the issue. Is the foreign key actually Linking the two tables. what am I getting wrong in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the **class_sections_id** column is null so there is never a matching entry in the classes_sections_table (sessions table) so there is no JOIN made and thus nothing to show.

As an example of how this would work take the following **classes table** :-

[image]

Now the **classes_sections** table :-
[image]

For English you will see that the **classes_sections_id**'s value is **1** this can correspond (aka associate with/reference etc) the classes_sections_ids column whose value is **1**.

The query

```
SELECT * FROM classes 
    INNER JOIN classes_sections 
        ON classes_sections.classes_sections_ids = classes.classes_sections_id 
    WHERE classes.classes_id =1
```

Would result in :-

[image]

However, if the following row were added to the classes table (**note the reference to the classes_sections_id column has a value of 700 and that there is no such row in the classes_sections table**) :-

[image]

If the query were changed to get id **4** then no rows will be returned because even though id 4 does exist (Chemistry) in the **classes** table there is no associated **classes_sections** row (*with a **classes_sections_ids** as **700***) so there is no JOIN and thus no row to return.

In short you need to have the **sections_id** column reference/associate/link to the **classes_sections_ids** column to retrieve any data.

> Is the foreign key actually Linking the two tables.

Specifying a FOREIGN KEY only specifies that a constraint exists (noting that `ON DELETE CASCADE` limits the constraint). It does not automatically define links, you have to do this.

You would likely do this programatically (I manually made the above links) e.g. when adding a class you would select one of the available sections, perhaps presented via a spinner (aka drop down selector). You then insert the class with the id of the selected section.

---

#### Additional

I believe that you will end up having issues with your design primarily due to how your are referencing/linking.

For example your design has a classes table that includes a column to link to the sections table. This without introducing the complexity of handling a list of links in a single column restricts a class to having a single section (same applies for teachers and students).

On the basis of the assumption that a class may have multiple sections then there is a further consideration, could a section be used by many classes (an example may be that all classes must start with evacuation procedures).

If the latter doesn't apply then the relationship between classes and sections could be one-many (or could be handled by a many-many relationship).

- In this case a section could have a column as a link to the class.

If the latter applies then the relationship between classes and sections would/should be a many-many relationship.

- In this case a link table (aka associative table, reference table, mapping table .....) would be used.
- Such a table has at least two columns each holding a link to the related tables (the combination would/should be unique).

As such I would suggest that you consider the following design (perhaps more to come) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS classes;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes ( class_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, class_name TEXT, class_codename TEXT );
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sections;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections ( section_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, section_name TEXT, section_description TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS teachers;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers ( teacher_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, teacher_name TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students ( student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, student_name TEXT);
-- LINK TABLES 
-- Note usess column constraints to define foreign keys i.e. REFERENCES
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS class_section_links;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS class_section_links (
    class_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES classes (class_id), 
    section_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES sections (section_id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (class_link, section_link));
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS class_teacher_links;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS class_teacher_links (
    class_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES classes (class_id), 
    teacher_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES teachers (teacher_id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (class_link, teacher_link));
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS class_student_links;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS class_student_links (
    class_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES classes (class_id),
    student_link INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES students (student_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (class_link, student_link));
```

This will load some data including some basics links between classes and sections :-

```
-- LOAD some data
-- CLASSES
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('English Language','EL100');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('English Literature','EL101');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('Applied Mathermatics','MA200');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('Pure Mathematics','MA201');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('Chemistry','SC300');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('Physics','SC301');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('Biology','SC302');
INSERT INTO classes (class_name, class_codename) VALUES('GEOGRAPHY','GE400');
-- SECTIONS
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Class Introduction','Evacuation procedures, amenities etc..');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Sentence Construction','Blah');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Word types','Basic word types such as VERB, ADJECTIVE etc');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Puntuation','Blah');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Under Milk Wood','Blah');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('Catcher in the Rye','Blah');
INSERT INTO sections (section_name, section_description) VALUES('The War of the Worlds','Blah');
-- CLASS SECTION LINKS (note assumes ID's of classes/sections in order 1,2,3......)
-- a) All classes have Class Introduction
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(1,1); -- Class 1 English language
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(2,1); -- Class 2 English Lit
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(3,1);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(6,1);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(7,1);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(8,1);
-- b) specific sections
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(1,2); -- Class 1 has section 2
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(1,3); -- Class 1 has section 3
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(2,5);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(2,6);
INSERT INTO class_section_links VALUES(2,7);
```

A query such as :-

```
SELECT class_name, class_codename, section_name, section_description 
FROM class_section_links 
    JOIN classes ON class_link = class_id 
    JOIN sections ON section_link = section_id 
ORDER BY class_name, section_name;
```

Would result in :-

[image]

If you look at **Class Introduction** you will see that just the one section is used many times, thus only needing a single set of data. So if there were a directive that instead of **Class Introduction** it be changed to **Introduction** then a single change would update ALL classes.

e.g. using the following to perform the update :-

```
UPDATE sections SET section_name = 'Introduction' WHERE section_name = 'Class Introduction';
```

and running the same query results in :-

[image]

Comment: Okay. Very nice illustration. But your  answer.   "In short you need to have the sections_id column reference/associate/link to the classes_sections_ids column to retrieve any data." how am I going to get this done?  Since the JOIN us not performing it's function. Is there any other function that could help?  @MikeT

Comment: You need to programatically make/define the links. All the JOIN is doing is to say get the rows from the other table based upon the selection (ON). As an example when obtaining the data for a class you may list (e.g. via a spinner) the classes_section. One would be selected, you'd then insert the class with the respective id of the classes_sections table. In the above I did this manually.

Comment: ok. Meaning, you cannot retrieve the classes sections based on the classes ID after JOINing the two tables @MikeT

Comment: Meaning this can only be achieved using a spinner? @MikeT

Comment: a) you can however you look at it from the point of view of the sections. e.g. (not tested) `SELECT * FROM sections JOIN classes ON classes_sections_ids = classes_section_id WHERE classes_id = 1` then you get list of sections for that class. b) Spinner would likely be ideal but some sort of list (if doing via user interface). However, I'm just about to update answer regarding design, which may not be as flexible as you need.

Comment: Your suggestion is very nice I must commend. But how about inserting into the classes_sessions table using a JOIN statement, does it make any sense. I am an android armature and programming in general so this is my thought process at this my level. @MikeT what do you think, could that be a solution?

Comment: though haven't yet tried your suggestion above @MikeT

Comment: You can't insert using a JOIN you can only insert into a specific table. I think your concept of what JOIN does is greater than what it actually does similar to how you perceived FOREIGN KEY. About to add a little more (load some data) to the answer (using the design I've suggested). Querying will follow.

Comment: You are not wrong with your assumptions above @MikeT. But what are the Link tables above in your updated answer meant to do. From your answer, I did not see a possible connection between classes_sections and classes tables, is that supposed to be done programmatically as well?

Comment: They cater for many-many relationship they are basically a map. Just added a query to answer which shows how they are used.

Comment: is this schema in your answer always used when creating such relationship as with my own case? @MikeT

Comment: This will take a little while to assimilate. so in short, you are saying.  **my problem is a design problem** , and  **The solution is a redesign as you proposed above**   right? @MikeT

Comment: Do you mean having a link table? I tend to opt for such a table as it caters for both one-many an many-many relationships. However, in some circumstances the link table may have additional columns for data specific to the link e.g. a student linked to a class may have a grade for that class, attendances etc.

Comment: What I see is that you may well have issues with your design. Not knowing what the intention of the App is I can't say for sure. However I strongly suspect that you will have issues. I'd suggest perhaps doing a search for relational database design and then when you understand what I am saying and to then visit the design factor.

Comment: I am currently making my research on the entire relational database concept but meanwhile, I have marked our suggestion as the right answer. But I think I still have a huge stone to pull off here

Answer (score 1):

Although not an answer to the question this may of of use.

Here's a quickly put together demo of how you can implement a link table within an App. Note it's very rudimentary.

The app will initially allows the input of a **class** (requires both fields to have data), clicking the button **Add Class** will attempt to add a class (should if both inputs have at least 1 character).

When a class has been added three additional inputs are made available (made visible) and additionally the class added will be listed. The new inputs are :-

- EditText For the Section Name
- EditText for the Section Description
- Spinner for the linked class (only single link is catered for, multiple's would come later)

When a section has been added then the section will be listed on the right and additionally the combined linked data will be listed below the column and section lists.

e.g.

[image]

### The Code

#### Layout - activity_main.xml

- (note package name would have to be changed)

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/heading"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/class_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/class_codename"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/addclass"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Add Class"/>
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/section_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/section_description"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/classselection"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </Spinner>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/addsection"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Add Section"/>
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id="@+id/lists"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/classlist"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </ListView>
      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/sectionlist"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/classsectionsinfo"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ListView>
  ```

#### Database Helper - DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "educator";
    public static final  int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_CLASSES = "classes";
    public static final String TB_SECTIONS = "sections";
    public static final String TB_CLASS_SECTION_LINKS = "class_section_links";


    public static final String COL_CLASSID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_CLASSNAME = "class_name";
    public static final String COl_CLASSCODENAME = "class_codename";
    public static final String COL_SECTIONID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_SECTIONNAME = "section_name";
    public static final String COL_SECTIONDESCRIPTION = "section_description";
    public static final String COL_CLASSLINK = "class_link";
    public static final String COL_SECTIONLINK = "section_link";
    public static final String COL_COMBINED = "info";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crttab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
        String crtclasses = crttab + TB_CLASSES +
                "(" +
                COL_CLASSID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_CLASSNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_CLASSCODENAME + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        String crtsections = crttab + TB_SECTIONS +
                "(" +
                COL_SECTIONID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_SECTIONNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_SECTIONDESCRIPTION + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        String crtclasssectionlink = crttab + TB_CLASS_SECTION_LINKS +
                "(" +
                COL_CLASSLINK + " INTEGER " +
                " REFERENCES " + TB_CLASSES + "(" + COL_CLASSID + ")," +
                COL_SECTIONLINK + " INTEGER " +
                " REFERENCES " + TB_SECTIONS + "(" + COL_SECTIONID + ") " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtclasses);
        db.execSQL(crtsections);
        db.execSQL(crtclasssectionlink);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public long addClass(String classname, String classcode) {
        if (classname.length() < 1 || classcode.length() < 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_CLASSNAME,classname);
        cv.put(COl_CLASSCODENAME,classcode);
        return mDB.insert(TB_CLASSES,null, cv);
    }

    public long addSection(String sectioname, String sectiondescription, long baseclass) {
        long sectionid = -1;
        if (sectioname.length() < 1 || sectiondescription.length() < 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_SECTIONNAME,sectioname);
        cv.put(COL_SECTIONDESCRIPTION,sectiondescription);
        sectionid = mDB.insert(TB_SECTIONS,null,cv);
        if (sectionid > 0 && baseclass > 0) {
            cv.clear();
            cv.put(COL_CLASSLINK,baseclass);
            cv.put(COL_SECTIONLINK,sectionid);
            mDB.insert(TB_CLASS_SECTION_LINKS,null,cv);
        }
        return sectionid;
    }

    public Cursor getClassAndSectionDetailsCombined() {
        //SELECT class_name||class_codename||section_name||section_description AS info
        // FROM class_section_links
        // JOIN classes ON class_link = classes._id
        // JOIN sections ON section_link = sections._id
        // ORDER BY class_name, section_name;

        return mDB.query(
                TB_CLASS_SECTION_LINKS +
                        " JOIN " + TB_CLASSES + " ON " +
                        COL_CLASSLINK + " = " + TB_CLASSES + "." + COL_CLASSID +
                        " JOIN " + TB_SECTIONS + " ON " +
                        COL_SECTIONLINK + " = " + TB_SECTIONS + "." + COL_SECTIONID,
                new String[] {
                        COl_CLASSNAME + "||" +
                                COl_CLASSCODENAME + "||" +
                                COL_SECTIONNAME + "||" +
                                COL_SECTIONDESCRIPTION +
                                " AS " + COL_COMBINED,
                "1 AS " + BaseColumns._ID},
                null,null,null, null,
                COl_CLASSNAME + "," + COL_SECTIONNAME
        );
    }

    public Cursor getClasses() {
        return mDB.query(TB_CLASSES,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getSections() {
        return mDB.query(TB_SECTIONS,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
    public long getSectionsCount() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,TB_SECTIONS);
    }
    public long getClassesCount() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,TB_CLASSES);
    }
}
```

- `getClassAndSectionDetailsCombined` differs a little from the commented SQL in that the cursor has two columns one being **_id**, this is to facilitate using CursorAdapters which require an _id column.

  - This is a quick/dirty/simplicity fix as _id will always be 1

#### the Activity - MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mClassName, mClassCode, mSectionName, mSectionDescription;
    Button mAddClass, mAddSection;
    ListView mClassList, mSectionList, mClassSectionInfoList;
    Spinner mClassSelection;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mClasses, mSections, mCLassSectionInfo;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCAClasses, mSCASections, mSCAClassSecInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mClassName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        mClassCode = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.class_codename);
        mSectionName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.section_name);
        mSectionDescription = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.section_description);
        mAddClass = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addclass);
        mAddSection = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addsection);
        mClassList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.classlist);
        mSectionList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.sectionlist);
        mClassSectionInfoList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.classsectionsinfo);
        mClassSelection = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.classselection);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        refreshDisplay();
        handleButtons();
    }

    private void handleButtons() {
        mAddClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((mClassName.getText().toString().length() > 0) &&
                        mClassCode.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    mDBHlpr.addClass(
                            mClassName.getText().toString(),
                            mClassCode.getText().toString()
                    );
                    refreshDisplay();
                }
            }
        });
        mAddSection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((mSectionName.getText().toString().length() > 0) &&
                        (mSectionDescription.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
                    mDBHlpr.addSection(
                            mSectionName.getText().toString(),
                            mSectionDescription.getText().toString(),
                            mClassSelection.getSelectedItemId()
                    );
                    refreshDisplay();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        // Only allow sections to be added if at least one Class exists
        if (mDBHlpr.getClassesCount() < 1) {
            mSectionName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSectionDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAddSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mSectionName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mSectionDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAddSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // Get Cursors from DB
        mClasses = mDBHlpr.getClasses();
        mSections = mDBHlpr.getSections();
        mCLassSectionInfo = mDBHlpr.getClassAndSectionDetailsCombined();

        // Prepare the Classes List Adapter or swap the cursor
        if (mSCAClasses == null) {
            mSCAClasses = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mClasses,new String[]{DBHelper.COl_CLASSNAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
        } else {
            mSCAClasses.swapCursor(mClasses);
        }
        // Prepare the Sections List Adapter
        if (mSCASections == null) {
            mSCASections = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSections,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COL_SECTIONNAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
        } else {
            mSCASections.swapCursor(mSections);
        }
        if (mSCAClassSecInfo == null) {
            mSCAClassSecInfo = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mCLassSectionInfo,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COL_COMBINED},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
        } else {
            mSCAClassSecInfo.swapCursor(mCLassSectionInfo);
        }
        mClassList.setAdapter(mSCAClasses);
        mClassList.setBackgroundColor(0xFF5555ff);
        mSectionList.setAdapter(mSCASections);
        mSectionList.setBackgroundColor(0xFF55FF55);
        mClassSelection.setAdapter(mSCAClasses);
        mClassSectionInfoList.setAdapter(mSCAClassSecInfo);
        mClassSectionInfoList.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFDD);
    }
}
```

Comment: After ours of countless trials, Boom!! it worked like magic. I studied your code, it took me a lot of time to wrap my head around it. I do really appreciate your time.

Comment: Steep learning curve but I believe you have what it takes to get there. Would be nice if you marked post this as being helpful, if it was that is.

Comment: but I have a couple of issues, from the diagram I for my App UI I guess you most have noticed I use recyclerview. Hence I used `getItemId(position)` method to get the Id to be passed to the database  `getClassAndSectionDetailsCombined` method. In the `selectQuery` I used the `Where clause` i.e `where classes_id = id` where `id` is id passed from the `getItemId(position)` in the adapter class.

Comment: but then, `class_sections` are only added to two ids irrespective of the number of classes I create. for instance, if I create classes 1 ,2 and 3 and add `class_sections` to all 3. sections are added to 1 and 2 currectly, any attempt to add sections to 3 or any other class after does not work, instead, the `classes_section` is added to either 1 or 2 while 3 remains with no `classes_session`. just seems sessions are misplaced

Comment: Have an Idea what could lead to this issue in my case.

Comment: and one more thing, is there no way to mark two answers as correct on StackOverflow?

Comment: Nope just one answer can be correct. You should probably re-check the first as the answer. P.S thanks for that. With regard to the issue I hope you're not using position as the id rather that you're using an intermediate array (cursors aren't fully supported by standard recyclerview, there are some posts that about adding swapCursor method). Position is unreliable (starts at 0 instead of 1 but then say delete 1st row and then it's two out, delete other rows and you just can't convert, this may well be the some are misplaced). I prefer cursors adapters as they return the id and are simpler.

Comment: but I am using 'getitemId(position)' from my adapter class.  I tested the value of this  ids o'clock from the logcat, they were uniform from 0 to the last number for the last 'recyclerview Item' there seems to be no issue.  Could the problem be from the query since the correct Id Is passed?

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma, oops sorry missed `getItemId(position)` that should be ok. It's when people pass the position as the id. Perhaps you aren't then getting/setting the correct value (e,g, you could perhaps have the classs id and section id mixed up).

Comment: I am still having issues with the Ids.  Some classes are matched correctly with their sections while some are not matched correctly with their sections. I don't really know how to go about with solving this problem. Meanwhile what does this part of your code actually do from the example you gave me. ( Check below)

Comment: `new String[] {
                        COl_CLASSNAME + "||" +
                                COl_CLASSCODENAME + "||" +                               COL_SECTIONNAME + "||" +
                                COL_SECTIONDESCRIPTION+
                                " AS " + COL_COMBINED,
                "1 AS 
}`

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma it creates 2 element String array for the 2 columns that will be returned from the query name, COL_COMBINED(resolves as info) (columns concatenated) and another called _id (purely to suit the CursorAdpater which must have a column named _id) that will have value of 1. i.e. you aren't limited to return just actual columns you can return derived columns. If you look at the lower list it's everything in all the columns without spaces. i.e. I was too lazy too create layout with multiple columns.

Comment: I have some confussions with regards to addSection() method. Can you explain the function of this method like technically. also what is the function of this line. `sectionid = mDB.insert(TB_SECTIONS,null,cv);` and how it was used in the code. sorry so much of these questions.

Comment: addSection will insert using the convenience SQLiteDatabase insert method (generates the SQL on your behalf). First parameter is the table as a string, the third parameter is a ContentValues object (array of column/value pairs). You create empty ContentValues then add the column/values pairs to be inserted. The second parameter allows you to specify a nullable column name to then allow all other columns to be default (I've never used this) null ignores the nullcolumnhack.[see update here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert)

Comment: ok, why the initiation here `long sectionid = -1;` in the `addSection()` method, why was it set to -1? and also the purpose for the if condition `if (sectionid > 0 && baseclass > 0) {`

Comment: -1 is not a valid id (rowid must be positive integer 1-9223372036854775807). So just in case setting it to indicate invalid id. Could've(should've??) used `return sectionid` *(I've a tendency to code with potential/known problems in mind)(well that's my excuse :))*